# Castle Windsor Register with implementation passed in on constructor

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, castle

In Castle Windsor I want a particular concrete implementation to be passed into the constructor of a container registered class.  Something like this (I know the syntax is illegal at the end ;-)):

```
var myConfig = new MyConfig();
container.Register(Component
  .For<IConnector>()
  .ImplementedBy<Connector>()
  .Parameters(myConfig));
```

Is there anyway I can pass in myConfig when ever Connector is created?  Is this possible?

(Connector has a constructor that takes MyConfig as a parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this:

```
   container.Register(Component
  .For<IConnector>()
  .ImplementedBy<Connector>()
  .ServiceOverrides(
   ServiceOverride
  .ForKey("myConfig")
  .Eq("NameYouGaveMyConfigWhenRegisteringInCastle"));
```

the ForKey("...") is the exact name of the parameter you pass into Connector for MyConfig.

The Eq.("...") is the name you give when you register MyConfig:

```
container.Register(Component
.For<IMyConfig>()
.ImplementedBy<MyConfig>()
.Named("config");
```

so you'd put in "config" where I typed "NameYouGaveMyConfig..."